# "with" macro in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, with-statement

I was looking for a macro that will resemble the with-construct.
The usage should be something like:

```
with (lock(&x), unlock(&x)) {
    ...
}
```

It might be useful for some other purposes.

I came up with this macro:

```
#define __with(_onenter, _onexit, v) \
    for (int __with_uniq##v=1; __with_uniq##v > 0; )\
        for (_onenter; __with_uniq##v > 0; _onexit) \
            while (__with_uniq##v-- > 0)

#define _with(x, y, z) __with(x, y, z)
#define with(_onenter, _onexit) _with(_onenter, _onexit, __COUNTER__)
```

It has 3 nested loops because it should:

1. Initialize loop counter (C99 only, of course)
2. Possibly initialize variable _onenter (such as `with (int fd=open(..), close(fd))`)
3. Allow `break` inside the code block. (`continue` is allowed too. And the macro could be adjusted to `assert()` it out)

I used it on the code for the XV6 OS and it seems quite useful.

My question is - what are the worst problems with such a macro? I mean, besides the mere usage of a C macro (especially one that implements new control-flow construct).

So far have found these drawbacks / problems:

1. No support for `return` or `goto` (but it can save some `goto`s in kernel code)
2. No support for errors (such as `fd < 0`). I think this one is fixable.
3. gnu89 / c99 and above only (loop counter. the unique variable trick is not necessary)
4. Somewhat less efficient than simple lock-unlock. I believe it to be insignificant.

Are there any other problems? Is there a better way to implement similar construct in C?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That macro scares me. I'd prefer the [traditional approach using `goto`s](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/894).

That approach is primitive, but most C programmers are familiar with the pattern and if they're not, they can understand it by reading the local code. There is no hidden behavior. As a consequence, it's pretty reliable.

Your macro is clever, but it would be new to most everybody and it comes with hidden gotchas. New contributors would have to be thought rules such as "don't `return` or `goto` out of a with block" and "`break` will break out of the with block, not out of the surrounding loop". I fear mistakes would be common.

The balance would shift if you could add warnings for misuses of this construct to the compiler. [With clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html), that seems to be an option. In this case, misuses would be detected and your code would remain portable to other compilers.

If you're willing to restrict yourself to GCC and Clang, you can use the [`cleanup`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#Common-Variable-Attributes) attribute. That would make your example look like this:

```
lock_t x = NULL __attribute__((cleanup(unlock)));
lock(&x);
```

And `unlock` will be called with a pointer to the variable when it goes out of scope. This is integrates with other language features like `return` and `goto`, and even with exceptions in mixed C/C++ projects.

Comment: Oh. response at last... Thank you, I didn't know about `cleanup` - sounds useful. Does the macro have more specific problems, besides its scariness?

Comment: The lack of support for `return` seems a deal-breaker, unless you're working  with a strict coding standard against `return` statements in the middle of functions. A `return` in a `with` block would look inconspicuous but would wreak havoc at run-time.

Comment: I understand, and agree that `return` is a big problem (so `cleanup` is much better). But doesn't `goto` require equally strict coding standard? What are the advantages of goto, in this respect?

Comment: Gotos, as used in the article I linked to, are primitive but most C programmers are familiar with the pattern and there is no hidden behavior. As a consequence, it's pretty reliable.

Your macro would be new to most everybody and it comes with hidden gotchas. It all depends on how quickly and reliable programmers will learn rules such as "don't `return` or `goto` out of a `with` block" and "`break` will break out of the `with` block, not out of the surrounding loop".

Comment: so what you say is something like, `goto`s are a warning sign, user-defined macros are not. ok.