# How to start scheme?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I am very new to scheme and i am trying to open it to try some codes.

Scheme  is located at

```
/usr/local/bin/scheme
```

I am coming to the directory and writing

```
scheme
```

to start it but it does not work. I get

```
scheme command not found
```

error.

[image]

What should i do to start the scheme and write the code? This should be a trivial question, sorry for that but i could not find what to do.

Thank you

Comment: In which way does it not work? Do you get an error message? Which one? Is /usr/local/bin in your `$PATH`?

Comment: This is not a programming question, and definitely not functional-programming question.

Comment: @Elazar do you think the following link is a programming question? Is it fair to write some fake code to make it look like a programming question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16197922/with-macro-in-c

Comment: @bigO: If you think it isn't fair, you should write it there. or flag it; Do not argue here. I did not say anything bad about your question - just that the tag is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a "command not found" error, that must mean that `/usr/local/bin` is not in your `$PATH`. You can either add it to your `$PATH`, call scheme using its absolute path (i.e. type `/usr/local/bin/scheme` instead of just `scheme`) or its relative path (i.e. type `./scheme` while in the `/usr/local/bin` directory).